# Issue with Creating a Search Bar with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a search bar that will load a list of user's names from an api when input is added to the search bar and im getting an error. im not quite sure what to make the parameters of the .filter method. or if im even using the correct method. I thought about using lodash _.filter but not sure how or where to implement that. im new to react so keep that in mind! id be very thankful for any suggestions

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: [],
      search: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?page=3&results=10&seed=abc")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ people: data.results }));
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
  }
  render() {

    let filteredPeople = this.state.people.filter(
      (people) => {
        return people.data.results.indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1;
        //or maybe use .includes
      }

    );
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="firstlast">
          {filteredPeople.map(people => (
            <div id="names">{people.name.first} {people.name.last}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

error message:

> Error in /~/App.js (43:32)
>   Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Comment: maybe because `people.data` doesn't contains a `results` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in input, you need to use that value to filter your data,

```
{ this.state.search !=="" ? this.state.people.filter( people => people.name.first.includes(this.state.search)).map( (people,index) => (
        <p key={index}>{people.name.first} {people.name.last}</p> 
    )) 
    :
    this.state.people.map((people,index) => (
        <p key={index}>{people.name.first} {people.name.last}</p> 
    ))
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fqaxqw)

**Note:** I have used `key={index}` because I didn't find anything unique in your response, but always try to avoid using `index` as `key`.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes sense. You just made my day!! @ravibagul91

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `people.results` instead of `people.data.results`

Cause `this.setState({ people: data.results })` adds `data.results` to people directly.

Comment: I just tried that and still getting error. This time it says: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined @ShmiliBreuer

Comment: What is `...indexOf(e.target.value)`  you may want to try `...indexOf(this.state.search)` instead. Hope this helps

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer is right.

`let filteredPeople = this.state.people.filter(
      (people) => {
        return people.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
        //or maybe use .includes
      }
`